# Accessing MovieClips in an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I think the answer is simple.

I created a variable for a MovieClip named enemyPerson.

I am "pushing" enemyPerson into an array(enemies).

I am trying to change the X of the each enemyPerson in the array to something different.

I have a timer triggering the function below, but when it triggers it just moves the same clip instead of adding another at a different location.

```
function spawningB1(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    enemies.push(enemyPerson);
    enemies[E].x = building1(260, 340); // this is a random number generater
    enemies[E].y = 158;
    addChild(enemies[E]);
    E++;                                // E is set to 0

}
```

Ideally, I would like to just keep adding more onto the stage. ( Leaving the originals in place)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a classID or create a class file for creating new instance. In your code, you only manipulate one Movieclip. If you are using AnimatieCC, juste create a classId[image]

```
function spawningB1(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    var spawnedEnemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
    spawnedEnemy.x = building1(260, 340);
    spawnedEnemy.y = 158

    addChild(spawnedEnemy);
    enemies.push(spawnedEnemy);

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I had this at the top of my code                                var EnemyPerson:MovieClip = new EnemyPerson

Comment: Your variable name cannot be exactly the same as any imported class names, so that line will likely produce an error.   Standard practice is to start all instances (variables) with a lower case letter, and to start all class names with an upper case letter.